# Javascript + Format of Integer Using Replace Function & Split Function

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript function, I want to concatenate a numbers.

```
Text Box value format `1.234.567,89`
```

But I split the value using "," and access two array having value as

```
First Array = 1.234.567
```

Then I used replace function to replace (.) dot by nothing, `to access simple integer : 1234567`

Code Sample

```
var number = element.value;
var numberArray = number.split(',');
numberArray[0] = numberArray[0].replace(/./g,"");
alert('numberArray[0]:'+numberArray[0]+'::numberArray[1]:'+numberArray[1]);
```

But I am getting numberArray[0] as null. Suggest something !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead

```
numberArray[0] = numberArray[0].replace(/[.]/g,"");
```

. (dot) matches every character in regex, enclosing it in [] changes the meaning

Comment: Or numberArray[0] = numberArray[0].replace(/\./g,""); will also do the job.

Comment: Agreed, I always find lots of forward and back slashes next to each other difficult to read